# Rendering IP address with react-native-public-ip in <Text>

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm struggling to render `publicIP` client-side inside of a Text block; I'm including `import publicIP from 'react-native-public-ip';` and have tried the following:

```
<Text>{publicIP()}</Text>
<Text>{ip()}</Text>
```

But nothing seems to take.

I'm able to render it with the example linked in their [README](https://github.com/teamairship/react-native-public-ip#usage), but not simply render as text. Any examples I find from Googling around use console.log as examples. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

publicIP() is asynchronous function

here is how you can make it:

```
[IP, setIP] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
 publicIP()
  .then(ip => {
    setIP(ip);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    setIP("error")
  });
},[])

return (
  <View>
    <Text>{IP}</Text>
  </View>
)
```